# Numpy array - Two unknown dimensions - png files

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, image-processing

I have a dataset existing of a bunch of png files with different sizes regarding their heights and widths.

I read in this files with the following code to get a numpy array. In this case, it is 2D. But actually I want to get a 3D array which exists of the number of images n, the height of the images h and the width w.

```
import os.path
import glob
import numpy as np

def open_images(images_directory):
    pattern_to_match = os.path.join(images_directory, "*.png")
    png_files = (x for x in glob.iglob(pattern_to_match)
                 if os.path.isfile(x))
    for current_png_filename in png_files:
        print("Opening file", current_png_filename)
        with open(current_png_filename, "rb") as current_png_file:
            data = current_png_file.read()
            return np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.uint8, offset=16)\
            .reshape(-1, 3)\
            .astype(np.float32)
            pass

directory_to_search = r"C:\Users\tobis\OneDrive\Desktop\Masterarbeit\data\2017-IWT4S-HDR_LP-dataset\crop_h1"
open_images(directory_to_search)
```

At the moment, I get an array with a shpae like this:
(21559, 3). I think the first number is a combination of width and height and the last is the RGB value. I would like to get an array that looks like this one: (n, h, w).

Is there a way to get such an array? Unfortunately, I have two unknown dimensions. This seems to be the problem...

Comment: This: different sizes regarding their heights and widths is going to be the biggest issue. numpy arrays are uniform so you either have to identify the biggest image and then zero-pad the rest, or choose an alternative structure to store them

Comment: That is not the width * height, and you are just getting lucky that you have a multiple of 12 bytes. PNGs are not flatfiles without metadata. Use PIL, scipy, matplotlib, cv2, libpng, or some other library to read the file correctly (or implement your own homegrown solution, but do it properly).

Comment: `21559` is a prime number so it's very unlikely that this represents an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just read an image file like that. You need to use a library to read it and interpret the height, width, colourspace, bits per pixel, date, the GPS data, the camera make and model and all the compressed, encoded pixels.

For example, with PIL/Pillow:

```
from PIL import Image 
import numpy as np 

# Open image and make sure it is RGB - not palette 
im = Image.open('image.png').convert('RGB') 

# Make into Numpy array 
na = np.array(im) 

# Check shape
print(na.shape)          # prints (480,640,3) for height, width, channels
```

Comment: Yes, that works for one image! Thank you! But I don't understand how to open multiple images with different sizes. My objective is to get an array or a data frame which I can use to train a neural network. All the solutions I found until now were solutions regarding images with two fixed dimensions but not with changing ones...

Comment: I don't do much with neural networks, so I don't know. I guess your options might be to pad (using `ImageOps.expand()` probably) with black to the size of the largest item in your data set, or to resize to a common size. I would suggest you ask a new question to get the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a flattened image and would like to recover the original row and column dimensions you can apply a heuristic that tests various possible combinations and checks the "smoothness" of the image along the row axis. This smoothness can be checked via the mean squared error of consecutive rows for example. This assumes that the original image has some kind of structure, also along the row axis, and so the change in consecutive pixels in the original image will be relatively small when compare to other possible shapes.

For example let's say the original image is `155 x 79` pixels and it has been flattened into an array of `155 * 79 == 12245`. The prime factorization of this is `5, 31, 79`. So the possible row dimensions are all unique combinations of these prime factors, i.e. `5, 31, 79, 155, 395, 2449`. Now these possible row dimensions, in the following referred to as *estimates*, can be sorted into two different categories:

1. Estimates which are a divisor of the original row dimension: `5`, `31` and `155`. This means effectively that multiple row-skipped copies of the original image are stacked next to each other. So the resulting image will retain the original column grouping. Since similar columns remain together each element of the stack will have roughly the same smoothness. For example if the estimate is `31` this means that the original shape `31 x 5 , 79` is transformed to `31 , 5 x 79`, i.e. only every 5-th row of the original image is considered and five such copies are stacked next to each other. For the original image (i.e. an estimate of `155`) length-1 correlations are considered (i.e. each pair of consecutive rows is compared), while for an estimate of `31` length-5 correlations are considered (i.e. comparing row-pairs that have another 4 rows between them). Since the original image is expected to have some smooth structure, the smoothness should decrease when longer ranges are compared. The decrease in smoothness will be bigger when the skip-range increases, but it can also completely vanish if the image contains some degree of periodicity along the row axis.
2. All other estimates: `79, 155, 395, 2449`. For estimates of this category different columns of the original image are mixed in the test image corresponding to the estimate. For example if the estimate is `79` we have `155 % 79 == 76`, i.e. each new row in the test image shifts the original columns by 3 with respect to the previous row. Assuming that the original image varies along the column dimension these shifts will introduce an increasingly strong deviation for the emerging consecutive rows. Since this column shift increases from row to row the resulting decrease in row-smoothness should be strong unless the number of rows is small. If the original image is column-periodic with the shift number of the estimate this can lead to a perfect agreement however.

So to summarize, if we compute the smoothness for all row dimension estimates we expect the smoothness to decrease for a wrong estimate and the decrease will be small if the estimate falls in category (1) and bigger if it falls in category (2).

**Important:** If the images are periodic along either the row or column dimension this can lead to a false estimate.

The implementation needs to cover the following steps:

1. Compute the prime factorization of the length of the flattened image.
2. Compute all unique row dimension estimates from combinations of the prime factors.
3. For each estimate compute the row-smoothness of the resulting test image. For example use the mean squared error of consecutive rows (actually this will be a non-smoothness score).
4. Find the best estimate from the scores.

Here is some example code for the implementation:

```
import itertools as it
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image


image = np.array(Image.open('example.jpg'))
original_shape = image.shape[:2]
image = image.reshape(-1, 3)


def compute_prime_factors(n):
    i = 2
    while i <= n:
        if n % i == 0:
            n //= i
            yield i
        else:
            i += 1

prime_factors = list(compute_prime_factors(len(image)))
combinations = it.chain.from_iterable(it.combinations(prime_factors, r=i) for i in range(1, len(prime_factors)))
row_dims = sorted({np.prod(x) for x in combinations})


def test_row_dim(r):
    c = len(image) // r
    test = image.reshape(r, c, 3)
    return np.mean((test[1:] - test[:-1])**2)


scores = [test_row_dim(r) for r in row_dims]
best_estimate = row_dims[np.argmin(scores)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set(xlabel='row dimension', ylabel='score')
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.plot(row_dims, scores, '-o', label='Estimations')
ax.plot([best_estimate], [np.min(scores)], '*', ms=12, label=f'Best Estimate ({best_estimate})')
ax.axvline(original_shape[0], label=f'Actual Dim ({original_shape[0]})', color='#2ca02c', zorder=-100, lw=1.5, ls='--')
ax.legend()

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(image.reshape(205, -1, 3))  # second best score

plt.show()
```

Let's test it on some image (`H x W: 410 x 640`):

[image: Example image]
<sup>Photo by Cameron Venti on Unsplash</sup>

This produces the following estimate scores:

[image: Scores]

The peaks to the left of the best estimate are the category (1) estimates that have the smallest row-skip. The prime factorization of `410` and `640` is `2*5*41` and `2**7 * 5` respectively. So the category (1) estimates that get closest to the original row dimension are `205`, `82` and `41` (the side peaks from right to left). A decreasing estimate implies an increasing row-skip range and hence an increasing MSE score. The peak to the left of the best estimate corresponds to an estimate of `205`, i.e. each second row gets skipped and hence two such row-skipped versions are stacked next to each other:

[image: Second best score]

As you can imagine, by skipping every second row, the image doesn't change too much and the change is the same for the two side-by-side versions. Hence the small difference to the original image's MSE score.

Comment: Fascinating reading. Is this approach something you developed and have reason to use often for some reason, or does it originate somewhere else you could disclose? I would be intrigued to hear anything more you can tell me about it... my name is Mark and my domain is theSetchells.com so you can deduce my Email pretty easily. In exchange, see lines 420-460 here for how libTiff does this... https://gitlab.com/libtiff/libtiff/-/blob/master/tools/raw2tiff.c

Comment: @MarkSetchell I never used this code before, I just came up with it in order to answer the question (which seems to have been concerned with a completely different problem though). I would test it on a wider range of images but I don't know of any image data set that contains images of varying dimensions.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the explanation. I often come across folk on Stack Overflow who don't know the dimensions, bytes per pixel, or channel ordering of their data and algorithms/heuristics to discover such parameters interest me.